# Customizing a view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, binding, swiftui

I just started using `SwiftUI` and play with it.
I am already facing this challenge.

I have a view with a slider:

```
struct RangeSpanView: View {
    @State var sliderValue = 0.0
    var minimumValue = 0.0
    var maximumValue = 100.0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Text("\(Int(minimumValue))")
                Slider(value: $sliderValue, in: minimumValue...maximumValue)
                Text("\(Int(maximumValue))")
            }.padding()
            Text("\(Int(sliderValue))")
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code where the view is loaded.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationLink(destination: RangeSpanView(),
                   label: {
                       .......... // Useful code.
    })
}
```

At this point, it doesn't do much but it works. Nevertheless here is what I want to do and I can't.

I need to be able to pass parameters to *RangeSpanView* so that I can decide custom values for *minimumValue* and *maximumValue* values of the slider. I have tried several variations of code I could think of or found by searching the net. But all of them either don't work or give some kind of errors.

The idea is that I want to have something like:

```
RangeSpanView(minSliderVal: 20, maxSliderVal: 470)
```

working so I can adapt the view to my needs.

Is this possible and what is the proper syntax for that?

Comment: This would work just like with any struct in Swift. So, either `RangeSpanView(minimumValue: 20, maximumValue: 470)` (and make the `sliderValue` private)... or create a custom `init(minSliderVal: Int, maxSliderVal: Int)`

Comment: Making the sliderValue private, produces an error message:
"Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'Binding<Double>'".

Comment: You changed this to `@State private var sliderValue = 0.0` and gave this error?!

Comment: Yes I tried about 2 or 3 variations and I think that was one of them.

Comment: I am now having this new challenge: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62669320/initializing-a-slider-value-in-swiftui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either remove the default values on minimumValue and maximumValue or add an init like:

```
init(
        minimumValue: CGFloat = 0.0,
        maximumValue: CGFloat = 100.0
    ) {
        self.minimumValue = minimumValue
        self.maximumValue = maximumValue
    }
```

or if you want those values to change to use a @Binding var, so that you can pass other @State variables on them from the view that is presenting it

Comment: It works using an init() function as you suggest.
The only issue that I am left with is the sliderValue.
Once I start using the slider it is OK.
But before, I see no way to enforce a consistent initial value, which is between the min and the max values.
There must be some solution to this problem. But what I have tried only leads to errors.

Comment: I made a new question for that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62669320/initializing-a-slider-value-in-swiftui